# send mail returns null

Tags: php, laravel, email

When trying to send a message, In my view **verifyEmail.blade.php** $agent is null and $agent->name says trying to get property of non object.

**verifyEmail.blade.php**

```
<body>
   <h2> Welcome to our website{{ $agent->name }} </h2>
   click <a href= "/user/verify/{{ $agent->verifyUser->token }}"> here </a> to verify your email   
</body>
```

This is how I am using the Mail class. In my Mail folder in verifyEmail file I have a construct function which collects the $agent model.

**verifyEmail.php**

```php
class verifyEmail extends Mailable
{
    
    public $agent;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($agent)
    {
        $this->$agent = $agent;
       
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.verifyEmail');
    }
}
```

And in my admin controller which does the registration for the user looks like this. The send method passes the agent model to the verifyEmail.php which was working in the tutorial I watched. How can I make agent model available in **verifyEmail.blade.php**

**AdminController**

```
  $agent = new agent($data);
    $agent->name = $data["name"];
    $agent->email = $data["email"];
    $agent->nrc = $data["nrc"];
    $agent->resident = $data["residents"];
    $agent->password = Hash::make($data["password"]);        
    $agent->save();
    
    verifyUser::create(
        [
            'token' => Str::random(60),
            'agent_id' => $agent->id,
        ]
        );
       
        Mail::to($agent->email)->send(new verifyEmail($agent));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there can be a slight modification in the code provided to solve this.

Inside the file verifyEmail.php, the line

```
    $this->$agent = $agent;
```

should be

```
    $this->agent = $agent;
```

Because $this->$agent might not be able to find the class level variable 'agent' and update its value that is provided in the constructor so it will have the default value null which is shown afterwards.

Comment: Oh my goodness I don't believe that was the issue. I kept on checking the vendor files to see how things are going under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring The Sender**

Using The `from` Method
First, let's explore configuring the sender of the email. Or, in other words, who the email is going to be "from". There are two ways to configure the sender. First, you may use the `from` method within your mailable class' `build` method:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

**Using A Global `from` Address**
However, if your application uses the same "from" address for all of its emails, it can become cumbersome to call the from method in each mailable class you generate. Instead, you may specify a global "from" address in your config/mail.php`configuration file. This address will be used if no other`"from" address is specified within the mailable class:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],
```

In addition, you may define a global "reply_to" address within your config/mail.php configuration file:

```
'reply_to' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],
```

So you can try this In `verifyEmail.php` Change this

```
 public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.verifyEmail');
    }
```

To this

```
public function build()
        {
            return $this->from('info@domain.com')->view('emails.verifyEmail');
        }
```

Comment: It is still producing the same error. I think the issue is with the build not picking the agent construct function or the send mail in AdminController is not  providing the construct with the agent model